# Is it bad design to pass function 2 levels down? What can be alternatives?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scene with componentA and this componentA have another componentB with buttons which should update scene.

My first guess is to pass function from scene to co componentB throught the CompoenentA but I'm new to React and I'm sure there is a better way.

How should ComponentB call for update on a whole scene?

Comment: If you mean that you want to pass a callback to another function that will in turn use it as a callback, then IMHO no, this isn't a sound way to go about it. The two components should both subscribe to a service/dispatcher of some kind with a named event, and when the service dispatches that event (usually because some other component somewhere else told it to), everybody subscribed will receive it. Consider, if you wanted another component aware of that same event, would you pass that same function down again? And again? No...just have them all get the event from one place.

Comment: I looked about a bit, here's something that shows eight ways to go about this in react. The version this guy was using may not be the most recent, but the general descriptions of solving this kind of problem in React seem solid. http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/

Comment: I agree with @TimConsolazio, two levels is probably too much, you should probably take a look at [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/)

Comment: I was thinking about Redux but since I just dive in this world I didn't want to apply another heavy library before I understand basic 'organic' way to do stuff. Anyways, that was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't consider what you described a bad design, nevertheless, if you are not happy with it, you can try to expose the `ComponentB` to the `Scene`, so `Scene` can pass the callback directly to `ComponentB`:

```js
// Scene.js
render() {
  <ComponentA>
    <ComponentB onCallback={this.callback} />
  </ComponentA>
}

// ComponentA.js
render() {
  <div>
    {this.props.children} // render ComponentB, or whatever you pass as children of ComponentA
  </div>
}
```

If the `ComponentA` has to pass props to `ComponentB`, consider moving this props to the `Scene` component.

This is a common pattern for components like menus:

```js
// App.js
render() {
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem onClick={this.handleMenuItem1Click} />
    <MenuItem onClick={this.handleMenuItem2Click} />
    <MenuItem onClick={this.handleMenuItem3Click} />
  </Menu>
}

// Menu.js
// <Menu> wraps its children in a styled div, and maybe add more behavior like expanding and collapsing
render() {
  <div>
    {this.props.children} // render MenuItem's
  </div>
}
```